# Maximizing a combinatorial identity

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, algorithms, discrete-optimization

So here is my problem. If we have a vector $\textbf{x}=(x_1,...,x_n)$ where $x_j \in \mathbb{N}$ for each $j \in \{1,...,n\}$, then is there a way to maximize the value of the following combinatorial identity:

$\sum_{j=1}^{n}\binom{2x_j}{2}$?

The problem here is that we do not know anything about the vector $\textbf{x}$ except for the fact that the entires are all natural numbers and that the constraint is $\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_{j}=k$ where $k\in \mathbb{N}$ is fixed.

Comment: The binomial coefficient $\binom{2x}{2} = x(2x - 1)$. This goes to infinity as $x$ goes to infinity, so you can make it as big as you want. Are you not missing some assumption?

Comment: Additionally, you use the phrase "combinatorial identity", but you in fact are working with a "combinatorial expression", i.e. there is no equals sign.

Answer (score 1):

Note that whenever $x$ and $y$ are positive integers,
$$
\binom{2(x+y)}2> \binom{2x}2+\binom{2y}2
$$
Therefore, if you have a vector $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ where there are two nonzero components, then you get a larger value of $\sum_i \binom{2x_i}2$ by combining those two nonzero components into one. This means that the vector which attains the optimum must have only one nonzero component, so it is some permutation of $(k,0,0,\dots,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

You want one component of $\bf x$ to have value $k$ and all the rest to be $0$.  Because the term ${2x_j \choose 2}=x_j(2x_j-1)$ you will increase the sum every time you move $1$ to the largest component from any other component.  This stops when one component equals $k$.